# Jenkins job failed java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java17/bin/java" (in directory "/"): e

Tags: maven, jenkins

Jenkins job failed due to

```
 ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java17/bin/java" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/api_test"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:254)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:223)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:997)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:509)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:280)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:802)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 13 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

**here is the Jenkins configuration:
jenkins tools configuration**

[image]

**job configuration**

[image]

Comment: Just naming it _Java 17_ doesn't make a _JDK **9**.0.4_ a _JDK **17**_. :)